# noty jquery plugin - toggle message show/hide using single button

Tags: jquery, togglebutton, noty

currently closing a noty message notification is possible using the 
closeWith: ['click'], // ['click', 'button', 'hover']

However this option requires the user interacting with the message notification.

Is it possible within the noty options for the button (on the web  page) that opened the message, to also dismiss it i.e. toggle message notification show/hide.

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 0):

To close all noty messages you can call:

```
$.noty.closeAll();
```

or

```
$.noty.close(id);
```

To close just one noty message

If you want to toggle the alert you can always just use plain jquery:

```
$(element).toggle();
```